# Javascript tree build with data return from MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tree, jstree

I want to build a Javascript / jQuery tree with a *structure* like this (ignore icons):

[image]

dfdf

The data for this tree will be generation in an MVC Controller, returning the data to the Javascript to build the tree.

Is there a Javascript library that can do this easily? I have played with jqTree but there's no documentation covering this. Ideally I am looking for something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tree"></div>
<div id="json" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#tree").on("click", function(){
   $("#json").load("/TreeController/LoadJSON/");
   $("#tree").loadJSONIntoTree("#json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

theres many plugins to create a tree like structure.
I've used [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) and liked. It can load data directly from json request

Comment: That website is down; I assumed it was discontinued.